# Передаваемый аргумент имеет значение float и datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

При попытке извлечения из даты в формате `datetime` года и числа недели возникает ошибка. Пример DataFrame:

```py
df.head()

    | ID | date_from  | date_to    |
    |----|------------|------------|
    | 1  | 2019-10-29 | 2020-05-04 |
    | 2  | 2019-01-29 | 2020-01-01 |
    | 3  | 2019-01-29 | 2020-04-15 |
```

При выполнении кода:

```
 df['date_from'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%W'))
```

возникает ошибка:

> TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'float'

В то же время:

```
df['date_from'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
```

выдаёт:

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

Comment: Что такое `df`?

Comment: pandas dataframe,

Comment: а что вы хотите получить в результате?

Comment: колонку, где в каждой строке будет значение формата <год>-<номер недели>, например 2019-50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [47]: df["date_from"].dt.strftime("%Y-%W")
Out[47]:
0    2019-43
1    2019-04
2    2019-04
Name: date_from, dtype: object
```

---

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность воспользоваться `.dt...` соответствующий столбец должен иметь тип данных `datetime64`. Если это строка, то сначала надо преобразовать данный столбец в `datetime64`:

```
df["date_from"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_from"], errors="coerce")
```

Comment: Приводит к `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: @Thistle, см. обновленный ответ...